# Why my string variable is not getting value when I try to assign with another variable having the value?

Tags: c++, string, stl, cout

I was just doing this code that converts a given time in 12-hour AM/PM format to military (24-hour) time. When the program gets compiled, it throws an error saying invalid argument for `stoi()`. When I debugged, I found that the argument of `stoi()`, which is the the `hr` variable is not holding a value for some reason. After checking further, I noticed that in addition to `hr`, the variables `min` and `sec` are also not getting their values assigned. I don't know why `hr=temp;`, `min=temp;` and `sec=temp;` are not working. Can someone please get me through this?

When I debugged, the `temp` value also cant be printed using `cout<<temp;` statement. Your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    
    string s="07:05:45PM";    // expected output is "19:05:45" in string format 
    int len=s.length();
    string temp, Time;
    string hr,min,sec;
    
    for(int i=0;i<len-2;i++) // loop excludes AM/PM part
    {
        if (i==0)            // condition for hr
        {
         temp[0]=s[i];
         temp[1]=s[i+1];
         hr=temp;
        
        i=2;                // updating i to reduce iteration
        }
        
        
        else if (i==3)     // condition for min
        {
        temp[0]=s[i];
        temp[1]=s[i+1];
        
        min=temp;

        i=5;
        }
        
        
        else if (i==6)     // for secs
        {
        temp[0]=s[i];
        temp[1]=s[i+1];
        sec=temp;
        }
    }
    
    if (s[len-1]=='A')
    {
        if (hr=="12")
            hr="00";
    }
    else 
    {
        if (hr!="12")
           {
              hr=to_string(stoi(hr)+12);
           }
    }


    
    Time.append(hr);
    Time.append(":");
    Time.append(min); 
    Time.append(":");
    Time.append(sec); 
    
    cout<<Time;
    
    
            
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Accessing `temp[0]` and `temp[1]` is an error, as `temp` is an empty string.

Comment: But when I print `temp[0]` and `temp[1]`, shows the value in each index. I also tried `temp.append(s[i]);`  instead of `temp[0]=s[i];`. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check the append function call? It should be used temp.append(s, i, 2). You can check it here: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/

Comment: Yes! It worked @Toothless. Thank you all once again! :)